# Grant select on future views snowflake

Tags: sql, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I grant select on all future views in a schema or database.
This works fine but I want the role to have access to all future views too:

```
grant select on view <schema>.<view> to role <role>;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grant on future objects](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html) like this (using ACCOUNTADMIN role):

Make sure USAGE is granted on database and schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE <database> TO ROLE <role>; 
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <database>.<schema> TO ROLE <role>;
```

Grant select on future objects:

```
grant select on future tables [views] in schema <database>.<schema> to role <role>;
grant select on future views in schema <database>.<schema> to role <role>;
```

Comment: Can also be done `in database db` rather than schema, if desired.

Comment: I run this as a sysadmin (the owner of the object) and get this error: "SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema '<schema>' ". Any ideas?

Comment: @Cristian Are you the owner of the schema ?

Comment: Yes sysadmin is the owner of database and schema.

Comment: @Cristian try to add usage on database and schema first: GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE <database> TO ROLE <role>;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <database>.<schema> TO ROLE <role>;

Comment: Same error. The ROLE have access to the schema and can do a select on all tables but every time I add a view or table I need to grant select. Im confused since I have the sysadmin role and sysadmin is the owner of the database and schema.

Comment: @Cristian the same discussion: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008xAAC6SAO/on-future-error-sql-access-control-error-insufficient-privileges-to-operate-on-schema-

Comment: Thank you @leftjoin  - For others to know - "SYSADMIN role doesn't have MANAGE GRANTS privilege (only security and account admins do), and for some reason ON FUTURE grant is dependant on having MANAGE GRANTS privilege, even if the role is owner of the object." I'm not an account or security admin so I cant do this.